# Using Arithmetic in SQL on my own columns to fill a third column where it is zero. (complicated, only when certain criteria is met)

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, math, case, parameterized-query

So here is my question. Brace yourself as it takes some thinking just to wrap your head around what I am trying to do. 
I'm working with `Quarterly census employment and wage data`. QCEW data has something called suppression codes. If a data denomination (comes in overall, location quotient, and over the year each year each quarter) is suppressed, then all the data for that denomination is zero. I have my table set up in the following way (only showing you columns that are relevant for the question):

```
A County_Id column,              
Industry_ID column,  
Year column,  
Qtr column,
```

Suppressed column (0 for not suppressed and 1 for suppressed),
Data_Category column (1 for overall, 2 for lq, and 3 for over the year),
Data_Denomination column (goes 1-8 for what specific data is being looked at in that category ex: monthly employment,Taxable wage, etc. typical data), 
and a value column (which will be zero if the Data_Category is suppressed - since all the data denomination values will be zero).

Now, if Overall data (cat 1) for, say, 1991 quarter 1 is suppressed, but the next year quarter 1 has both overall and over the year (cats 1 and 3) NOT suppressed, then we can infer what the value would be for that first year's suppressed data, since `OTY1991q1 = (Overall1991q1 - Overall1990q1)`. So to find that suppressed data we would just subtract our cat 1 (denom 1-8) values from our cat 3 (denom 1-8) values to replace the zeroes that are in our suppressed values from the year before. It's fairly easy to grasp mathematically, the difficulty is that there are millions of columns with which to check for these criteria. I'm trying to write some kind of SQL query that would do this for me, check to make sure Overall-n qtr-n is suppressed, then look to see if the next year isn't for both overall and oty, (in maybe some sort of complicated case statement? Then if those criteria are met, perform the arithmetic for the two Data_Cat-Data_Denom categories and replace the zero in the respective Cat-Denom values.

Below is a simple sample (non-relevant data_cats removed) that I hope will help get what I'm trying to do across.

```
|CountyID IndustryID Year Qtr Suppressed Data_Cat Data_Denom Value                                                                          
| 5            10      1990  1      1          1        1        0                                                                                                                                                     
| 5            10      1990  1      1          1        2        0                                                                                                                                                     
| 5            10      1990  1      1          1        3        0                                                                                                                                                     
| 5            10      1991  1      0          1        1        5                                                                                                                                                     
| 5            10      1991  1      0          1        2        15                                                                                                                                                    
| 5            10      1991  1      0          1        3        25                                                                                                                                                    
| 5            10      1991  1      0          3        1        20                                                                                                                                                    
| 5            10      1991  1      0          3        2        20                                                                                                                                                    
| 5            10      1991  1      0          3        3        35
```

So basically what we're trying to do here is take the overall data from each data category (I removed lq ~ data_cat 2) because it isn't relevant and data_denom (which I've narrowed down from 8 to 3 for simplicity) in 1991, subtract it from the overall 1991 value and that will give you the applicable
| value for the previous year's 1990 cat_1. So here data_cat 1 Data_denom 1 would be 15 (20-5), denom 2 would be 5(20-15), and denom 3 would be 10(35-25). (Oty 1991q1 - overall 1991q1) = 1990q1. I hope this helps. Like I said the problem isn't the math it's formulating a query that will check this criteria millions and millions of times.

Comment: This will be a lot easier if you can provide some dummy data and your desired output from that data.

Comment: I have a sample excel file I've set up that more streamlines what I'm trying to do, but this is the first time I've asked a question, is there a way to share the file on this page?

Comment: https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/ -- and format as code in your question

Comment: Updated answer to test on example data from the question update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find supressed data that has 2 rows of unsupressed data for the next year and quarter, we could use cross apply() to do something like this:

test setup: http://rextester.com/ORNCFR23551

using `cross apply()` to return rows with a valid derived value:

```
select t.*
  , NewValue = cat3.value - cat1.value
from t
  cross apply (
      select i.value 
      from t as i
      where i.CountyID   = t.CountyID
        and i.IndustryID = t.IndustryID
        and i.Data_Denom = t.Data_Denom 
        and i.Year       = t.Year +1
        and i.Qtr        = t.Qtr
        and i.Suppressed = 0
        and i.Data_Cat   = 1
  ) cat1
  cross apply (
      select i.value 
      from t as i
      where i.CountyID   = t.CountyID
        and i.IndustryID = t.IndustryID
        and i.Data_Denom = t.Data_Denom 
        and i.Year       = t.Year +1
        and i.Qtr        = t.Qtr 
        and i.Suppressed = 0
        and i.Data_Cat   = 3
  ) cat3
where t.Suppressed = 1
  and t.Data_Cat   = 1
```

returns:

```
+----------+------------+------+-----+------------+----------+------------+-------+----------+
| CountyID | IndustryID | Year | Qtr | Suppressed | Data_Cat | Data_Denom | Value | NewValue |
+----------+------------+------+-----+------------+----------+------------+-------+----------+
|        5 |         10 | 1990 |   1 |          1 |        1 |          1 |     0 |       15 |
|        5 |         10 | 1990 |   1 |          1 |        1 |          2 |     0 |        5 |
|        5 |         10 | 1990 |   1 |          1 |        1 |          3 |     0 |       10 |
+----------+------------+------+-----+------------+----------+------------+-------+----------+
```

---

Using `outer apply()` to return all rows

```
select t.*
  , NewValue = coalesce(nullif(t.value,0),cat3.value - cat1.value,0)
from t
  outer apply (
      select i.value 
      from t as i
      where i.CountyID   = t.CountyID
        and i.IndustryID = t.IndustryID
        and i.Data_Denom = t.Data_Denom 
        and i.Year       = t.Year +1
        and i.Qtr        = t.Qtr
        and i.Suppressed = 0
        and i.Data_Cat   = 1
  ) cat1
  outer apply (
      select i.value 
      from t as i
      where i.CountyID   = t.CountyID
        and i.IndustryID = t.IndustryID
        and i.Data_Denom = t.Data_Denom 
        and i.Year       = t.Year +1
        and i.Qtr        = t.Qtr
        and i.Suppressed = 0
        and i.Data_Cat   = 3
  ) cat3
```

returns:

```
+----------+------------+------+-----+------------+----------+------------+-------+----------+
| CountyID | IndustryID | Year | Qtr | Suppressed | Data_Cat | Data_Denom | Value | NewValue |
+----------+------------+------+-----+------------+----------+------------+-------+----------+
|        5 |         10 | 1990 |   1 |          1 |        1 |          1 |     0 |       15 |
|        5 |         10 | 1990 |   1 |          1 |        1 |          2 |     0 |        5 |
|        5 |         10 | 1990 |   1 |          1 |        1 |          3 |     0 |       10 |
|        5 |         10 | 1991 |   1 |          0 |        1 |          1 |     5 |        5 |
|        5 |         10 | 1991 |   1 |          0 |        1 |          2 |    15 |       15 |
|        5 |         10 | 1991 |   1 |          0 |        1 |          3 |    25 |       25 |
|        5 |         10 | 1991 |   1 |          0 |        3 |          1 |    20 |       20 |
|        5 |         10 | 1991 |   1 |          0 |        3 |          2 |    20 |       20 |
|        5 |         10 | 1991 |   1 |          0 |        3 |          3 |    35 |       35 |
+----------+------------+------+-----+------------+----------+------------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Well, sure, but none of the examples from your link actually apply to *this query*.  (We're not joining on an inequality, or on `TOP n`; or doing anything that can't be handled with `INNER JOIN`.)  If the physical design is good, the `INNER JOIN` will perform fine; if it's not, no query will perform well.

Comment: Thanks SqlZim, your code works as well. Is there any way to alter it in a way that allows for this to happen across multiple years? Say you had the same phenomenon occur from years 1992 to 1993, but you wanted to update both inferred values from the four years with the same select statement. Is there a way to do this, or is this asking too much?

Comment: @J.Jack I'm not sure I understand your question. If two consecutive years are suppressed, how do you get the Cat3 value for the suppressed year to use on the second suppressed year?

Comment: Imagine 1990 is suppressed, but 1991 isn't, so we are able to infer what 1990's overall data will be. Now instead of just two years, we also have 1992 and 1993. 1993 isn't suppressed, however, 1992 is. So it's (suppressed, not, suppressed, not) Is there a way to write a query that will do what we did above for 1990 and 1991, but return the new values of both sets of two years? My backup to there not being a way to do this is to make tables for every two years, do these calculations, and combine them all at the end with an [insert into select] statement. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @J.Jack I don't have any problems running the code with multiple years the way you are describing. http://rextester.com/YLP24313 Are you seeing something that I'm not?

Comment: No, I got it to work, it was a simple mistake on my end with the way my sample was formatted. Thank you!

Comment: Hey SqlZim, if I wanted to add another condition for the calculation: that a column called Own_code was the same across time, how would I go about that? Imagine that there is a duplicate of the original 1990 overall data that is suppressed but has an ownership code that doesn't match the original data, the calculation will be done for both sets of 1990 data regardless, because it satisfies the other criteria. Is there a way to get around this? Could you just include i.own_code = t.own_code in all the where statements? If this needs to be made more clear let me know and I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: @J.Jack Yes, `i.own_code = t.own_code` would cover it unless it is nullable, then you just account for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1** - fixed some column names

**UPDATE 2** - improved aliases in 2nd query

---

Ok, I think I get it.

If you're *just* wanting to make that one inference, then the following may help.  (If this is just the first of many inferences you want to make in filling data gaps, you may find that a different method leads to a more efficient solution for doing both/all of them, but I guess cross that bridge when you get there...)

While much of the basic logic stays the same, how you'd tweak it depends on whether you want a query *just* to provide the values you would infer (e.g. to drive an `UPDATE` statement), or whether you want to use this logic inline in a bigger query.  For performance reasons, I suspect the former makes more sense (especially if you can do the update once and then read the resulting dataset many times), so I'll start by framing things that way and come back to the other in a moment...

It sounds like you have a single table (I'll call it `QCEW`) with all these columns.  In that case, use joins to associate each suppressed overall datapoint (`c_oa` in the following code) with the corresponding overall and oty datapoints from a year later:

```
SELECT c_oa.*, n_oa.value - n_oty.value inferred_value
  FROM           QCEW c_oa    --current yr/qtr overall
      inner join QCEW n_oa    --next yr (same qtr) overall
              on c_oa.countyId = n_oa.countyId
             and c_oa.industryId = n_oa.industryId
             and c_oa.year = n_oa.year - 1
             and c_oa.qtr = n_oa.qtr
             and c_oa.data_denom = n_oa.data_denom
      inner join QCEW n_oty   --next yr (same qtr) over-the-year
              on c_oa.countyId = n_oty.countyId
             and c_oa.industryId = n_oty.industryId
             and c_oa.year = n_oty.year - 1
             and c_oa.qtr = n_oty.qtr
             and c_oa.data_denom = n_oty.data_denom
 WHERE c_oa.SUPPRESSED = 1
   AND c_oa.DATA_CAT = 1
   AND n_oa.SUPPRESSED = 0
   AND n_oa.DATA_CAT = 1
   AND n_oty.SUPPRESSED = 0
   AND n_oty.DATA_CAT = 3
```

Now it sounds like the table is big, and we've just joined 3 instances of it; so for this to work you'll need good physical design (appropriate indexes/stats for join columns, etc.).  And that's why I'd suggest doing an update based on the above query once; sure, it may run long, but then you can read the inferred values in no time.

But if you really want to merge this directly into a query of the data you could modify it some to show *all* values, with inferred values mixed in.  We need to switch to outer joins to do this, and I'm going to do some slightly weird things with join conditions to make it fit together:

```
SELECT src.COUNTYID
     , src.INDUSTRYID
     , src.YEAR
     , src.QTR
     , case when (n_oa.value - n_oty.value) is null 
            then src.suppressed 
            else 2
       end as SUPPRESSED_CODE -- 0=NOT SUPPRESSED, 1=SUPPRESSED, 2=INFERRED
     , src.DATA_CAT
     , src.DATA_DENOM
     , coalesce(n_oa.value - n_oty.value, src.value) as VALUE
  FROM          QCEW src     --a source row from which we'll generate a record
      left join QCEW n_oa    --next yr (same qtr) overall (if src is suppressed/overall)
             on src.countyId = n_oa.countyId
            and src.industryId = n_oa.industryId
            and src.year = n_oa.year - 1
            and src.qtr = n_oa.qtr
            and src.data_denom = n_oa.data_denom
            and src.SUPPRESSED = 1 and n_oa.SUPPRESSED = 0
            and src.DATA_CAT = 1 and n_oa.DATA_CAT = 1
      left join QCEW n_oty   --next yr (same qtr) over-the-year (if src is suppressed/overall)
             on src.countyId = n_oty.countyId
            and src.industryId = n_oty.industryId
            and src.year = n_oty.year - 1
            and src.qtr = n_oty.qtr
            and src.data_denom = n_oty.data_denom
            and src.SUPPRESSED = 1 and n_oty.SUPPRESSED = 0
            and src.DATA_CAT = 1 and n_oty.DATA_CAT = 3
```

Comment: Would that second set of code work with the table formatted as above? I'm also a little confused about you using the c_oa. as a suppressed overall data point. You can select things that don't yet exist? I apologize, but like I said I actually only started learning SQL in January so while I'm picking it up quickly, there's still a lot I don't know because I haven't had to actually do it.

Comment: **Will it work w/ a table formatted as above?**  Unless I'm missing something, the above matches my assumptions (except column names, which I'll update).  I'll try to see if I'm missing something; but also you could test the query over a sample of data and see if it does as you want.

Comment: **[Can you] select things that don't yet exist?"**  I don't understand the question; what thing that doesn't exist do I appear to be selecting?

Comment: Re the 2nd question: I think what you mean might have to do with the difference between join conditions (especially for outer joins) and filters as would appear in the `WHERE` clause. In the 2nd query two join conditions each specify `c_oa.SUPPRESSED=1`; but since these are (outer) join conditions, that doesn't filter out rows where `c_oa.SUPPRESSED<>1`; it just prevents that join from associating any rows with such a `c_oa` record.

Comment: I think I'm just misinterpreting what your c_oa actually is.                                   I'll go ahead and try this code on a sample and get back to you

Comment: In the first query `c_oa` is specifically the set of suppressed overall data points.  In the 2nd query I should've renamed it I guess, because in the 2nd query `c_oa` is the main data point from which the result record is generated.

Comment: To clarify - I've updated the 2nd query to use `src` in reference to the source data (the table).

Comment: So oddly when I try the 2nd code on a sample I receive the result of "The multi-part identifier "src_oa.Suppressed" could not be bound." However when I ran it replacing the src with the original c_oa, the query ran, and completed, but failed to actually replace the zero values with the numbers needed. What is the line "case when (n_oa.value - n_oty.value) is null" trying to do? I don't think the value will ever be null because the values are zero when the data is suppressed, not null. Is this an issue? Thank you for all your help by the way, I definitely feel closer to a solution!

Comment: `src_oa` is the wrong identifier.  In one version of the query I used `c_oa`, in a later version I used `src`, but `src_oa` isn't a thing.  Switch it to whichever (`c_oa` or `src`) you used throughout the query and I think it will be ok

Comment: To answer the question about `NULL` - the `NULL` values are the product of outer joins.  When a (left) outer join condition doesn't match any rows, instead of the record being dropped (as with an inner join) it is paired with a fake row that contains all NULL values.

Comment: (I found the src_oa reference I'd missed in the code above and fixed it, by the way.  Sorry about that.)

Comment: Testing with an SQL fiddle to see if I'm missing something

Comment: Hmm... appears to me to be working (at least with this latest version).  The SQL fiddle uses the wrong DBMS, but nothing I'm doing should behave any differently on SQL Server...  Can you provide a sample showing it not work, so I can see if I'm missing some weird case?

Comment: *Sigh* tried to edit a prior comment instead of post another one, but stackoverflow is messing with me.  Anyway, here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eabda/5/0  Note I had to strip comments from the SQL.  If you can change it around to show a failure perhaps I can fix it.

Comment: Thanks Mark, this worked really well for what I was trying to do and I appreciate the help, sorry for getting back to you late. Is there an easy way to shift around what calculation I am trying to do? For example, instead of n_oa - n_oty, instead doing something like n_oty + c_oa (next year's over the year + this years overall)? I'm fiddling with it on my own, so no pressure to get back to me.

Comment: Also, is there a way to do this where if I have multiple years, it will go from year to year and fill in these data gaps? The way this code is set up, it will only perform the two latest years.

Comment: I would think this could be adapted to other calculations, just making sure a left join brings in each data point used in the calculation then performing the calculation in a `coalesce` or `case` as above. BUT if you plan to do many different inferences, you might want to look at some more efficient (but perhaps less intuitive) approaches. As for multiple years, I'm not seeing why this shouldn't work for any number of years' data. If I get a chance I'll update the fiddle to show this; or let me know if you're seeing something I've missed...